# How to put 4-seconds delay while changing the background image of a buttan in Android

Tags: android

I have two buttons in my sample application and I want to change the background image of the buttons one after another with 4-seconds delay, So far i have developed the code, you can see it below, but it gets sleep  my application and display nothing.

Please somebody help me that I could do so.

```
   int m =0;
    int delay = 4;  //Seconds

    while(m < 4)
    {



     // int i = (int) (Math.random() * num + 1);

    if(m==0)
    {
        button1.postDelayed(new Runnable()
        {
            public void run()
            {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            button1.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.buttonyellow);
            m++;
            }
        }, 1000*delay);

    }


    else if(m==1)
    {
        button2.postDelayed(new Runnable()
        {
            public void run()
            {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                button2.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.buttonyellow);
                m++;
            }
        }, 1000*delay);

    }





    if(m==2)
    {
        button1.postDelayed(new Runnable()
        {
            public void run()
            {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            button1.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.buttonblue);
            m++;
            }
        }, 1000*delay);

    }


    else if(m==3)
    {
        button2.postDelayed(new Runnable()
        {
            public void run()
            {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                button2.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.buttonblue);
                m++;
            }
        }, 1000*delay);

    }



    }
```

Comment: start with researching how postDelayed works. (also, you code as posted does not compile, as m is local and used in an anonymous class)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
int mark = 0; 

button2.postDelayed(new Runnable()
    {
        public void run()
        {
            switch(mark++){
                 case 0:button2.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.buttonyellow); break;
                 case 1:button2.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.buttongreen); break;
                 ..ect
            }
            if(mark==Max)mark=0;

         button2.postDelayed(this,4000);
        }
    }, 4000);
```

Note, this will go on till the end of time, or when your app stops.

Answer (score 1):

`postDelayed` doesn't delay execution of the current thread, so your thread is stuck posting the `m == 0` case repeatedly.

You probably want your posted Runnable to invoke some method that not only sets the background and increments the number, but also calls this logic (to choose a new Runnable to post) again.

e.g. (warning: untested code)

```
// assuming button1 and button2 are available
new Runnable() {
  private int m = 0;
  private final int delay = 4000;

  @Override
  public void run() {
    if (m == 0) {
      button1.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.buttonyellow);
      button1.postDelayed(this, delay);
    } else if (m == 1) {
      button2.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.buttonyellow);
      button2.postDelayed(this, delay);
    }
    // more cases here -- also consider making m wrap around
    m++;
  }
}.run();
```

Naturally this should be invoked on the UI thread (if it's not called on the UI thread, it should be dispatched to the UI thread with `post` or similar).

Comment: Plz make the approperiate chages in for if(m==0) in my code that i could pick your idea.

Comment: Not sure what you mean by "appropriate changes" here.

Comment: Would someone please explain why this response has been downvoted twice with no comment?

Comment: Your code is a little convoluted, you have it running in Runnable(its own thread), and then you have that same runnable being run on the ui thread via posting it to the buttons Handler.

Comment: It is not running on its own thread. The first time, it runs on the same thread it was invoked on (presumably the UI thread, otherwise a changing .run to a post (rather than postDelayed) would be appropriate. But usually this sort of thing is fired in response to a UI event (e.g. `onStart`), so the initial post is unnecessary.

Comment: You are right, Edit your answer a little so ital let me remove my downvote.

Answer (score -1):

Your while loop is causing your UI thread to wait for these operations to complete. Your best two options would be to call this inside a new thread:

```
new Runnable() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        //Your code
    }
}.run();
```

Or to embed them in a chain:

```
button1.postDelayed(new Runnable()
    {
        public void run()
        {
            button1.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.buttonyellow);
            button2.postDelayed(new Runnable()
            {
                public void run()
                {
                    button2.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.buttonyellow);
                    button1.postDelayed(new Runnable()
                    {
                        public void run()
                        {
                            button1.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.buttonblue);
                            button2.postDelayed(new Runnable()
                            {
                                public void run()
                                {
                                    button2.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.buttonblue);
                                }
                            }, 1000*delay);
                         }
                    }, 1000*delay);
                }
            }, 1000*delay);
        }
    }, 1000*delay);
```